# Proof using truth tables and an equivalence

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I am solving this problem:

Show that $p \to q \equiv \neg p ∨ q$ using a truth table.

I'm lost. Any help would be appreciated. I don't known how to start.

Comment: Do you know how to make a truth table for $\lnot \,p\lor q$?

Comment: I do not, sorry.

Comment: @LavoriziaVaughn Please see my answer, for details on how to approch it.

Comment: Thank you so very much

Comment: @LavoriziaVaughn if this helped you please consider accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you are starting with Logic for the first time, the idea is to prove that when one of the propositions is true then the other one as well, and when one is false the other one as well.

So we start by seeing that  as proposition $\neg p ∨ q$ is false only when both of components is false, in case one of them is true then it is automatically true. Similar $p \to q$ is false only when the premise or hypothesis is true but the conclusion is not, in any other case it is true.

We can see this reasoning in a table:

$$\begin{array}{r|r|r|r} p& q & \neg p & p\to q & \neg p \vee q \\
 T& T & F & T & T \\
  T& F & F & F & F\\
 F& T & T & T & T \\
 F& F & T & T & T
\end{array} $$

As you can see now, both propositions have the same values of truth, then they are equivalent.